# Add class to all elements which have a certain class when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add a class named "group" to all elements which have the class "someClass" - but only , e.g.:

```
<div class="someClass">SomeText</div>
<div class="someClass">SomeOtherText</div>
<div class="someOtherClass">SomeMoreText</div>
<div class="someOtherClass">SomeMoreOtherText</div>
```

Should become to the following if user clicks on a div containing the class "someClass":

```
<div class="someClass group">SomeText</div>
<div class="someClass group">SomeOtherText</div>
<div class="someOtherClass">SomeMoreText</div>
<div class="someOtherClass">SomeMoreOtherText</div>
```

If the user clicks on a div containing "someOtherClass" those should get added the class "group".

I tried the following jQuery - unsuccessfully:

```
$("#someId").live("click", function() {    
    var selectedClass;
    selectedClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('.'+selectedClass).addClass('group');
    //...followed by more jQuery...
});
```

I also tried my luck with:

```
$("#someId").live("click", function() {    
    $(this).attr('class').addClass('group');
    //...followed by more jQuery...
});
```

...which didn't work either :(

Comment: What if an element has more than one class?

Comment: Why were you putting backslashes before your single quotes. As you can see from the syntax highlighting in your question, that's not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to take into account the possibility of divs having more than one class -- which will happen whenever a div is clicked twice in a row:

```
​$('div').on('click',function(e) {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class'),
        carr = cl.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<carr.length; i++) {
        $('div.'+carr[i]).addClass('newclass');
    };
});​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcXu5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function() {    
    var selectedClass;
    selectedClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.'+selectedClass).addClass('group');
});​
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/H3hs9/1/

Like that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the divs being clicked upon have exactly one class:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $('.group').removeClass('group'); //assuming you want this
  $('.'+this.className).addClass('group');
});
```

If they may have many:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $('.group').removeClass('group'); //assuming you want this
  var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
  var select  = $.map(classes,function(c){ return "."+c }).join();
  $(select).addClass('group');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.someClass').on('click',function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.attr('class')=='someClass'){
            $this.addClass('group');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses an approach of toggle the class on and off.

HTML

```
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
<div class="item someclass">Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.group{
color:green;
}​
```

JS

```
jQuery('.item').click(function(){

    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('group')){
    jQuery(this).addClass('group')
    }
    else
    {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('group')
    }
    });​
```

When you click on some element with class "item" it search if has the class "group". If true, removes the class, if false add the class.

Using the click event on divs with "item" element it's good when you only want to add the class with a certain group of elements.

The fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/nNS44/

Comment: The class name could be "item" or something different. As in my example either "someClass" or "someOtherClass". But again, it could be totally different from those as well. It should listen for the clicked element only.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.someOtherClass').on('click',function(){
            $('.someClass').addClass('group');

        });
    });
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ekx7Z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try some jquery like so:

```
$("#someId").click(function(){
    $("div.someClass").addclass("group");
});
```